# Find the least days of visit from set date in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite

This is what i did :`in case of avg per class`

```
select cust_classes,
         avg(InvoiceDate("2017-12-31") - (InvoiceDate)) as 
         avg_least_days 
         from tbl 
         group by cust_classes
```

it gives `0` so i thought maybe it is zero. Thus is tested like this:
To see the least days of visit for each customer.`non avg query as the question`

```
select cust_id,cust_classes,
             (InvoiceDate("2017-12-31") - (InvoiceDate)) as 
             avg_least_days 
             from tbl
```

and it returned `0` for everyone which is not right.

Whats is the problem?
The desired output:

```
cust_id  num_days_from_last_visit
1           3
2           12
3           9
```

Comment: Does something in your question refer to a column in the table?

Comment: I edited the question as your answer to show what i did in my dataset correctly but it doesn't work. InvoiceDate is a column indeed.Can you find whats the problem?

Comment: Please provide some sample data and your desired output. (See [How to
format SQL tables in a Stack Overflow
post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96125) for how to add some.)

Answer (score 2):

This should work, assuming `visit_date` is a column in your table:

```
select t.ethnicity,
       avg(julianday('2017-12-31') - julianday(t.visit_date)) as 
avg_least_days 
from table_1 t
group by t.ethnicity;
```